# Using libVLC for Android on windows platform

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to explore libVLC for Android that's why setting up VLC android project on windows 7 but i'm facing problems. When i import the project and setup all helping libraries and try to compile using NDK it gives following error

```
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `jni/..//modules/codec/omxil/iomx.cpp', 
needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/iomx gingerbread/__//modules/codec/omxil/iomx.o'.  Stop.
```

While when i try to search the file in my folder i only able to find iomx.h and iomx.cpp is actually missing but i downloaded the project from official repository.

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc-ports/android.git
```

I'm willing to follow a tutorial with proper configurations to setup and compile android application of VLC but i'm not able to find any tutorial and the official one says that it is for Linux and you will require a Linux or Mac OSX to follow this tutorial [Tutorial Link](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile). So my first question is

- Can we Compile VLC android project Using all mentioned tools like (Android SDK, NDK, ant etc) on a windows platform.
- Secondly i'm not able to find a detailed or much easy Documentation except this one [VLC Documentation link](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html), Are there any other easy to understand libVLC documentation more specific to android usage

Please help me or guide me in right direction. I want to develop an application for Docked DVD device for android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer about this by myself and today watched this question unanswered so thought to answer it so that it can be helpful for others.

For the first part the answer is 'NO' we cannot compile the libVLC code on Windows OS using NDK as due to complex compilation process of libVLC. it Cannot be compiled using NDK tools that's why VLC released a script to compile libVLC which is in main directory when you download code from Git repository named Compile.sh and it can be run only on linux or mac as both based on Unix. i.e for libVLC compilation you need to run compile.sh which requires alot of linux based tools as mentioned in their official tutorial for compilation. you can try all those packages through cygwin on windows but i have not tried that rather i switched to Ubuntu 13.04 so that i can also explore linux environment...:). One thing i like to mention here if your target is just to use the compiled C++ code of libVLC in your project through java then you can do this on windows OS using libVLC.so file but if you need to change the libVLC code and recompile it then you will need to run compile.sh which requires linux or mac.

For the Second one the answer is same that as far as i know the only documentation i found was that i mentioned in my question.

Comment: libvlc is written in c++ which is language also used by android for it's core libraries you can use it in your project for the features provided by vlc. All that i found about it is in above liks please explore them.

Comment: ok, i have gone through the links though i will still go through them again, incase i get anything